# Make a POST API call when app is running in Background mode in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have this requirement of fetching user locations as per defined frequency. For that, I'm using **Background Modes(Location Updates)** from Xcode Capabilities.

[image]

After capturing user location data, the app should also post this data to the server by making a **POST API** call. This should happen even when the app is in **Background state, or killed by a user.**

How do I achieve this functionality? Do Background Modes helps here too?

Comment: You can use thread by which you can call api in fews second continuously

Comment: @sunilkumar Does that work when the app is in ***Not Running*** state?

Comment: For regular location updates, if the app is killed by the user then it doesn't run.  Simple as that. They killed it. They didn't want it to run. For all other cases you can update your server in response to the location update (assuming you have asked for and received "always permission" or have activated background location updates). You can use significant location change updates to be relaunched; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati

Comment: That's appreciable, @Paulw11 ! Can you assist me in the latter part of the question? Making API Call in the background state or when the app is not running(if that's possible)

Comment: Nothing special about it. Just make a POST call using URLSession,for example, in `didUpdateLocation`.

Comment: @Paulw11 If the app is killed by the user then location updates don't work then how Whatsapp shares live location for 8 hours even if the app is killed?

Comment: Use significant location updates